# Phpunit, testing a method that calls a method from repository with arguments

Tags: php, laravel-5, phpunit

I want to test a public method which calls a method from different class with methods as the arguments.

```
 public function __construct(LeadData $leadData,LeadRepository $leadRepository){....}
 public function proceedtosave($leads,$payout,$received)
{
    try {
        //save the lead
        $this->savedLead = $this->leadRepository->leadCreate($leads,$payout,$received);
        $this->responseData['lead_id'] = $this->savedLead->id;

    } catch (QueryException $exception) {
        $errorCode = $exception->errorInfo[1];
        Log::info(['Lead insert error code: '.$errorCode,'Error message: '.$exception->getMessage()]);
        if ($this->validator->errorCodeChecker($errorCode) === false) {
            $this->leadDuplicateRepository->leadDuplicateCreate($this->leads, $payout, $received);
            return $this->validator->getErrors();
        }
    }
}
```

This is how I wrote the test

```
/**
 * @test
 * 
 */
public function save_leads_to_leads_table_if_not_duplicate()
{
    $this->getLeadsForValidator();
    $leadData = $this->getMock('App\Helpers\..\..Data');        
    $leadIn = $this->getMockbuilder('App\Helpers\Repositories\..Interface')
                ->setMethods(array('leadCreate'))
                ->getMock();
    $leadIn->expects($this->once())
            ->method('leadCreate')
            ->will($this->returnValue(1));
            $leadIn->leadCreate($this->results,1,2);
    $this->SUT = new LeadStore($leadData,$leadIn);
    $this->SUT->proceedtosave($this->results,1,2);
}
```

I updated my original question here since I realized that I have to refactor my code. How would you pass this test?I got the error which I am trying to solve

```
 1) StoreLeadsTest::save_leads_to_leads_table_if_not_duplicate
 .....::leadCreate(Array (...), 1, 2) was not expected to be called more than once.
 /home/vagrant/Code/l.../../LeadStore.php:87
 /home/vagrant/Code/./../StoreLeadsTest.php:46
```

And the lines of code

```
    $this->savedLead = $this->leadRepository->leadCreate($leads,$payout,$received);//LeadStore.php:87

    $this->SUT->proceedtosave($this->results,1,2);//StoreLeadsTest.php:46
```

Swapping Mockery expectations from

```
  ->expects($this->once())
```

To

```
  ->expects($this->any())
```

Will result ErrorException

```
  ErrorException: Trying to get property of non-object
```

That point to this line of code

```
  $this->responseData['lead_id'] = $this->savedLead->id;
```

If I remove that line above, my test pass, how to make phpunit skip that line so that I can continue to test the other lines?

Comment: Can you please post a stack trace? This will determine where the 'Trying to get property of non-object' is occurring. 

From first glance it might be to do with `$this-results` as it does not appear to be set in you setup() method.

Comment: @thomasstuttard , I updated my question, I cant produce stack trace , this code is working in development, I amjust trying to pass the test so that I can have bases for future refactor.The $this->results is a protected property which exists when calling the  $this->getLeadsForValidator().